# Pending tasks in puppet dashboard?

Tags: puppet

My puppet master dashboard console shows `x PENDING TASKS` and it keeps on increasing. 
How do I rectify it? Whenever I change any conf file, it does not get reflected in the dashboard. even if the node gets deleted also it is not reflected in the console?
how to delete the puppet cache? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

Check the status of the worker threads and maybe restart them:

```
/etc/init.d/puppet-dashboard-workers status
```

Check the logfile for errors:

```
tail -f /usr/share/puppet-dashboard/log/delayed_job.log
```

You might be able to get the file name with this:

```
grep "Importing report" /usr/share/puppet-dashboard/log/delayed_job.log
```

If you have found that one report is responsible for the errors, check the report files here:

```
/usr/share/puppet-dashboard/spool
```

Answer (score 2):

From the 'Dashboard Manual: Installing' at http://docs.puppetlabs.com/dashboard/manual/1.2/bootstrapping.html#starting-and-managing-delayed-job-workers:

> Dashboard uses a delayed_job queue to asynchronously process resource-intensive tasks. Although Dashboard won’t lose any data sent by puppet masters if these jobs don’t run, you’ll need to be running at least one delayed job worker (and preferably one per CPU core) to get the full benefit of Dashboard’s UI.

For testing the dashboard I had success using the jobs:work Rake Task:

```
$ sudo -u puppet-dashboard rake RAILS_ENV=production jobs:work
```

When going to production the recommended road is to use a production-quality web server, for example Apache with the Passenger module.

Dario